# White space at bottom of WebView in JQuery mobile

Tags: android, css, jquery-mobile

I am using 1.0a3 version of jquery-mobile. The problem is that a white space of approx. 40 px is added to the bottom of a WebView. In the Android emulator the white space doesn't appear always, when it does, i get a `Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout` warning. On a 2.3.3. device the white space does always show up.

I tried switching to version 1.0a2, 1.0a4 and 1.0b2, but on 1.0a2 the screen goes blank on orientation change, and on 1.0b2 and 1.0a4 split button appearance changes in a not desired way. I haven't changed nothing myself in the css.

What could be the things to change to get rid of the white space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the `min-height` attribute in the .css file. I replaced `min-height: 100%` with `min-height: 500px` in .ui-page and .ui-page-active elements and it removed the issue. As a side effect, the gradient color is more expanded, but that should not be a big problem.